# Puma workers not booting in Rails 5.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 VM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ubuntu, puma

I was learning to deploy a demo rails app using `Capistrano`, with `Puma` as an app server and `Nginx` web server accordingly. I've set up the necessary puma configurations in a file, `_stage.rb`, and later set `puma` as a `SysVinit` service as `/etc/init.d/puma_myarticles_staging`. The executable file, `puma_init.sh.erb` was later written into the remote server as `puma_init.sh` which looked like,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Puma rack web server"
NAME=puma_<%=fetch(:full_app_name)%>
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/${NAME}
APP_ROOT=<%=current_path%>
PIDFILE=<%= fetch(:puma_pid) %>
STATE_FILE=<%= fetch(:puma_state) %>

log_daemon_msg() { echo "$@"; }
log_end_msg() { [ $1 -eq 0 ] && RES=OK; logger ${RES:=FAIL}; }

run_pumactl(){
  [ $# -lt 1 ] && echo "$# params were given, Expected 1" && exit 1
  cd ${APP_ROOT} && <%= fetch(:rbenv_prefix) %> bundle exec pumactl -F <%=fetch(:puma_conf)%> $1
}

# Function that starts the puma
#
start_task() {
  if [ -e ${PIDFILE} ]; then
    PID=`cat ${PIDFILE}`
    # If the puma isn't running, run it, otherwise restart it.
    if [ "`ps -A -o pid= | grep -c ${PID}`" -eq 0 ]; then
      do_start_task
    else
      restart_task
    fi
  else
    do_start_task
  fi
}
do_start_task() {
  log_daemon_msg "--> Woke up puma ${APP_ROOT}"
  run_pumactl start
}

# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
stop_task() {
  log_daemon_msg "--> Stopping puma in path: ${APP_ROOT} ..."
  if [ -e ${PIDFILE} ]; then
    PID=`cat ${PIDFILE}`
    if [ "`ps -A -o pid= | grep -c ${PID}`" -eq 0 ]; then
      log_daemon_msg "--> Puma isn't running in path: ${APP_ROOT}."
    else
      log_daemon_msg "--> About to kill puma with PID: `cat $PIDFILE` ..."
      if [ "`ps -A -o pid= | grep -c ${PID}`" -eq 0 ]; then
        log_daemon_msg "--> Puma isn't running in path: ${APP_ROOT}."
        return 0
      else
        run_pumactl stop
        log_daemon_msg "--> Waiting for status ..."
        sleep 5
        if [ "`ps -A -o pid= | grep -c ${PID}`" -eq 0 ]; then
          log_daemon_msg "--> Puma with pid ${PID} stopped successfully."
          rm -f ${PIDFILE} ${STATE_FILE}
        else
          log_daemon_msg "--> Unable to stop puma with pid ${PID}."
        fi
      fi
    fi
  else
    log_daemon_msg "--> Puma isn't running in path: ${APP_ROOT}."
  fi
  return 0
}

# Function that sends a SIGUSR2 to the daemon/service
#
restart_task() {
  if [ -e ${PIDFILE} ]; then
    log_daemon_msg "--> About to restart puma in path: ${APP_ROOT} ..."
    run_pumactl restart
  else
    log_daemon_msg "--> Your puma was never playing... Let's get it out there first ..."
    start_task
  fi
  return 0
}

# Function that sends a SIGUSR2 to the daemon/service
#
status_task() {
  if [ -e ${PIDFILE} ]; then
    log_daemon_msg "--> About to status puma ${APP_ROOT} ..."
    run_pumactl status
  else
    log_daemon_msg "---> Puma isn't running in path: ${APP_ROOT}."
  fi
  return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting ${DESC}" "${NAME} ..."
    start_task
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping ${DESC}" "${NAME} ..."
    stop_task
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  status)
    log_daemon_msg "Status ${DESC}" "${NAME} ..."
    status_task
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  restart)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting ${DESC}" "${NAME} ..."
    restart_task
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage:" >&2
    echo "  ${SCRIPT_NAME} {start|stop|status|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
:
```

The `puma.rb` was,

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

directory '/app/myarticles_staging/current'
environment 'staging'

pidfile '/app/myarticles_staging/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid'
state_path '/app/myarticles_staging/shared/tmp/states/puma.state'
stdout_redirect '/app/myarticles_staging/shared/log/puma_access.log', '/app/myarticles_staging/shared/log/puma_error.log', true

daemonize

threads 4, 8

bind 'unix:///app/myarticles_staging/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.myarticles_staging.sock'

activate_control_app 'unix:///app/myarticles_staging/shared/tmp/sockets/pumactl.myarticles_staging.sock'

workers '4'

preload_app!

on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file('/app/myarticles_staging/shared/config/database.yml')['staging'])
end

# Allow puma to be restarted by the `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Where I'm fetching all the puma configurations from a file named `_stage.rb` that looks like,

```
set :stage, :staging
set :branch, :staging

set :server_port, 80

set :full_app_name, "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}"
set :rails_env, :staging

set :deploy_to, "/app/#{fetch(:full_app_name)}"

set :puma_user, fetch(:deploy_user)
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/states/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru')}
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.#{fetch(:full_app_name)}.sock"
set :puma_default_control_app, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/pumactl.#{fetch(:full_app_name)}.sock"
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/config/puma.rb"
set :puma_workers, 4
set :puma_threads, [4, 8]
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, :staging
set :puma_preload_app, true

set :puma_enable_socket_service, true
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"

set :nginx_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/nginx_access.log"
set :nginx_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/nginx_error.log"
```

When I started the puma service as `/etc/init.d/puma_myarticles_staging start`, it outputs,

```
Starting Puma rack web server puma_myarticles_staging ...
--> Woke up puma /app/myarticles_staging/current
[3955] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[3955] * Version 4.3.12 (ruby 2.7.0-p0), codename: Mysterious Traveller
[3955] * Min threads: 4, max threads: 8
[3955] * Environment: staging
[3955] * Process workers: 1
[3955] * Preloading application
[3955] * Listening on unix:///app/myarticles_staging/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.myarticles_staging.sock
[3955] ! WARNING: Detected 1 Thread(s) started in app boot:
[3955] ! #<Thread:0x000055c692868bf8 /app/myarticles_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:323 sleep> - /app/myarticles_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:329:in `sleep'
[3955] * Daemonizing...
```

Leaving no new puma pid or state files behind. Eventually, the puma service workers didn't boot as I checked the `puma.pid` and `puma.state` there are no files being written. When I ran `rbenv exec bundle exec rails s` to test manually on the `current_path` it worked.

I checked for the puma process that was demonized using `ps ax | grep puma`, but didn't find the actual puma workers,

```
1516 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the puma error log getting populated with any information?

Comment: @jamesc no. nothing is written to `stderr`. I think its some internal bug of `puma`

Comment: What are the contents of your puma service. Have you set it up  as a user service? i.e. in the users `~/home/.config folder`?

Comment: Your on_worker_boot doesn't look quite right!

Comment: `on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end
`

Comment: You don't seem to be setting up your socket. I've posted an answer that may or may not help you

Comment: @jamesc you can see the modified question that I've set up my socket, pids, and puma state separately in a file. could you suggest if there was a better way to set puma as a systemd service than I did?

Comment: Can you check your nginx error logs please

Comment: Nginx throws `connection refused` to the puma socket upstream connection. I've setup the puma on a `TCP` port and later used `nginx`, and it worked perfectly. But with the puma socket, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should try a user systemctl service, I will update my answer with an example of how to do this shortly

Comment: Just spotted your stage.rb config is using shared_path variable a lot but you don't set it anywhere that I can see that will cause a problem

Comment: `shared_path` is a capistrano global variable that automatically outputs `/DEPLOY_PATH/APP_NAME`, mine outputs `/app/myarticles_staging/shared/` as you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is with the way puma is being started. I'm pretty certain there is no Puma bug here.
You haven't posted any detail about your systemctl setup but best practice is to use a user service file that way puma will always be started on boot and no passwords are needed

A standard puma config that I use goes something like this

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

# Change to match your CPU core count
workers 0

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#

rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
#shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"
shared_dir = "/home/project/apps/comtech/shared" # Use your projects path

# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
#pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "pids/server.pid" }

pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app

# Set up socket location
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/comtech_puma.sock"

on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked web server processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
# preload_app!

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Obviously you will need to set the `ENVIRONMENT` variable to staging on the server

Adjust the pids folder accordingly to use tmp.

To use a user service rather than a system service take a look at the following

`cd ~/.config/systemd/user` creating the folders if they don’t exist

`nano name_of_your_puma.service` and paste following contents adjusting paths accordingly.

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma Rack Server
# Puma supports systemd's `Type=notify` and watchdog service
# monitoring, if the [sd_notify](https://github.com/agis/ruby-sdnotify) gem is installed,
# as of Puma 5.1 or later.
# On earlier versions of Puma or JRuby, change this to `Type=simple` and remove
# the `WatchdogSec` line.

[Service]
Type=simple

# If your Puma process locks up, systemd's watchdog will restart it within seconds.
#WatchdogSec=10
RestartSec=10

WorkingDirectory=/home/comtech/apps/comtech/current
#PIDFile=/home/comtech/apps/comtech/shared/pids/puma.pid
#User=comtech

ExecStart=/home/comtech/.rvm/bin/rvm 3.1.3@comtech_cms_app do bundle exec puma -C /home/comtech/apps/comtech/current/config/puma_production.rb
ExecStop=/home/comtech/.rvm/bin/rvm 3.1.3@comtech_cms_app do bundle exec pumactl -S /home/comtech/apps/comtech/shared/pids/puma.state stop
ExecReload=/home/comtech/.rvm/bin/rvm 3.1.3@ruby-3.1.3@comtech_cms_app do bundle exec pumactl -S /home/comtech/apps/comtech/shared/pids/puma.state restart
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run

```
$ systemctl --user enable name_of_your_puma.service
```

To checkup on the service

```
$ systemctl --user status
```

To stop the service

```
$ systemctl --user stop
```

To start the service

```
$ systemctl --user start
```

The service will automatically start on boot and will restart puma if puma fails.
Also note I' using RVM, so you need to adjust the start command accordingly

Comment: thanks for your answer, it finally worked with your suggested configuration. I've modified  your  `systemctl` service a little bit for future references.